# Issues using pageSheet in iOS 12, Xcode 10

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I'm trying to recreate the effect where the view controller underneath the one I'm presenting onto the user's iPhone is positioned behind the presented view controller so you can see the top of the previous VC.

```
@objc func showSteps() {
    let vc = UIStoryboard(name: Storyboards.Main.rawValue, bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: HowToSteps.four.stepAsString())
    vc.modalPresentationStyle = .pageSheet // I've also tried the other enum options here to no effect

    let nc = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc)
    present(nc, animated: true)
}
```

However the presented view controller just comes up as full screen without the ability to see the view controller underneath behind it.

Any help here would be appreciated. Thanks!

Edit:

The effect I'm going for:

[image]

Comment: `.pageSheet` (and `.formSheet`) only give different results on an iPad.

Comment: Thanks @rmaddy. Do you have any advice on how to achieve the desired result in the image above? I see it's standard in iOS 13, however my app supports 12 as the base version. Is this something I need to custom build or is easily baked in?

Comment: It would be completely custom in iOS 12. Personally, I would let iOS 12 show as iOS  12 does and let iOS 13 show its new way. Might be confusing to iOS 12 users to see the new look. But if you do want to do it, you are going to need to implement your own custom transition.